# php token match does not work

Tags: php, smarty, token

i am doing form validator(using tokens).
Page is based on smarty. So in class Articles i have the followin function:

```html
public static function getToken(){
  self::$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
  $_SESSION['token'] = self::$token;
 }
```

Then in .tpl file i have inserted the value like this:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{Articles::$token}">
```

After the form is submitted the check is run in index.php:

```html
if(isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){
 Articles::addComment($item, $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comment']);
}
```

The issue is that I get different tokens. For example, I echoed the `$_SESSION['token']` and compared in with the value in the form (view source).
Also after submit i tried to echo both values `($_SESSION ['token']` and `$_POST ['token])` they are different as well. Obviously, the form is not submitting.

Comment: why they should be the same? on second request `getToken` generated new token and overwrote one in SESSION, which is of course different from first one

Comment: @Lashane, could you please elaborate a little more. I do not follow where it is considered the second request. I call the function only once.

Comment: when you post form - it is second request, and you definitely call getToken 2nd time

Comment: Could you please suggest something? im quite new to this.

Comment: @Benua if new token gets generated on second request use a simple conditional of `if(empty($_SESSION['token'])) { getToken()}`

Comment: Dumb question: Are you actually calling `session_start()` to start/open the session in *both* requests?

Comment: @Benua there is nothing wrong with a single session-life-long token. Having multiple or one-time tokens does not make it secure.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF tokens need not be mapped 1:1 for users. What if you have more than one form on a page? What if a user has more than one browser window open?

Define something to store `0..n` tokens, set a reasonably short validity period on them, and [optionally] define *what* they are valid for. Eg:

```
class Token {
    protected $id, $expiry;

    public function __construct($expiry=300, $id=NULL) {
        $this->expiry = time() + $expiry;
        if( is_null($id) ) {
            // actual secure ID generation.
            $this->id = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
        } else {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
    }

    public function getID() {
        return $id;
    }

    public function isValid() {
        return time() < $expiry;
    }
}

class YourApp {
    public function newToken() {
        $token = new Token();
        $_SESSION['tokens'][$token->getID()] = $token;
        return $token
    }

    public function checkToken($token_id) {
        if( key_exists($token_id, $_SESSION['tokens']) ) {
            $cur = $_SESSION['tokens'][$token_id];
            unset($_SESSION['tokens'][$token_id]; // single use only!
            return $cur->isValid();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function flushOldTokens() {
        $_SESSION['tokens'] = array_filter(
            $_SESSION['tokens'],
            function($t){return $t->isValid();}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: "What if you have more than one form on a page?" --- so, what then? What's wrong with having a single non-expiring and non-single use csrf token?

Comment: @zerkms then you leave yourself open to tokens being intercepted and used by malicious actors.

Comment: If tokens can be intercepted - having multiple tokens does not protect from anything: once a token is stolen - it can quickly be used. (and the legit user's request would fail). So, your suggestion does not solve it.